# Linq to SQL C# Get Products in all child/sub child Categories too slow

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

What would be the best way to get all the products in all the child categories of a selected main category?
Trying to get 10000 products in about 80 child categories but this method is too slow. Any suggestions?
Using c# and Linq to SQL

```
//list for the child categories
private List<int> catsChildList = new List<int>();

GetChildCats(123);

//get all the child categories of main category '123'

private void GetChildCats(int _parentCat)
{
    var cats = (from c in db2.tbl_cart_categories
                where c.ParentID == _parentCat
                select new { c.CategoryID });
    if (cats.Count() > 0)
    {
        foreach (var cat in cats)
        {
            int _cat = Convert.ToInt32(cat.CategoryID);
            catsChildList.Add(_cat);
            GetChildCats(_cat);
        }
    }
}

//Get the products
var products = (from p in db2.products_infos
            where  p.IsEnabled == true
            group p by p.ProdID
            into g where g.Any(x => catsChildList.Contains(Convert.ToInt32(x.CategoryID)))
```

takes about 6 seconds to return results

Comment: do you have the appropriate indexes? is this entity framework or linq to sql?

Comment: are you allowed to change CategoryID from varchar to int?

Comment: yeah Indexes are there. It's Linq to SQL.

CategoryID is int but accepts null. Main Categories parent ID is null

THanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the difference between

```
var products = 
    (
     from p in db2.products_infos
     where  p.IsEnabled == true
     group p by p.ProdID
     into g where g.Any(x => catsChildList.Contains(Convert.ToInt32(x.CategoryID)))
     select g
    );
```

and

```
 var tmpList = 
    (
     from p in db2.products_infos
     where  p.IsEnabled == true 
            && catsChildList.Contains(Convert.ToInt32(p.CategoryID))) 
     select p
    ).ToList();

 var products = 
     (from r in tmpList group p by r.ProdID into g select g);
```

?

Maybe my schema is different, but when I try this with Linq2Sql it seems to return the same results, but the latter returns the results all in one database hit, whereas the former issues multiple requests. (If the number of products returned is 10000, it would be doing 10001 database requests).

Comment: Amazing! This worked great. Loads in less than 1 second. Thank you

Comment: Why is it that .ToList(); makes it run fast but without it it loads very slow?

Comment: The .ToList() forces the products to be retrieved at that stage and that is a fairly straight-forward query. The grouping is then done  in-memory. Without the .ToList(), you are asking Linq2SQL to do both the grouping and selecting, and it doesn't appear to make a great job of it. Note, if you just wanted the number of products per category (and not the products details), then the .ToList() would slow things down since it would be mean returning the details of the 10000 products and then grouping and counting them, whereas without the .ToList(), it will ask the sql to group and count them.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the stats & code provided, you should save 3 seconds by removing this line:

```
if (cats.Count() > 0)
```

... because it doubles the enumerations (and given that means you're doubling your database calls, it's flat out bad) *and* is pretty much pointless since there's nothing after it that would crash if Count == 0.

If you're hitting a MS SQL Server, the Profiler they provide is your friend here because you would likely see an extra database hit.

Comment: If they do need to check, they should use `cats.Any()` or get rid of it since the `foreach` won't even loop.

Comment: I imagine `Any` would also result in an extra database hit here but good point.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunalty That didn't help much. I believe the issue is with g.Any(x => catsChildList.Contains(Convert.ToInt32(x.CategoryID). Having to check each product against the list.

Answer (score 0):

a. The following line of code is a lambda expression replacement of first line through GetChildCats() method.

```
var findCatList = (List<int> parent) => {        
    from c in db2.tbl_cart_categories
            where  & c.ParentID == _parentCat
            select (db2.tbl_cart_categories.Any(cat=> cat.ParentID == c.CategoryID) ?
                findCatList(c.CategoryID)
                :new { c.CategoryID }                    
                )}

var catList = findCatList(123);
```

But even this would do the recursion, but would be done internally. Please check that out. Of course its an untested code, just based on your objects.

b. Other think you can try is, your can try replacing db2.tbl_cart_categories to db2.tbl_cart_categories.AsParallel(). I am not sure about how Object Context/ Data Context behave with this. But db2 is not a context object then I am sure it would better the performance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, although you don't specify, I am assuming you are using Linq to Sql. Please update your question to include that information.

Start by adding some basic profiling. Which query is taking the longest to run?

```
g.Any(x => catsChildList.Contains(Convert.ToInt32(x.CategoryID)))
```

This is definitely suspicious. If catsChildList has a lot of values, you could potentially be generating a huge IN clause, which is always going to run slowly. You can verify that by checking the actual SQL statement that is being run.

The truth is that recursive hierarchy traversal like this is never going to be efficient when you are trying to perform every iteration in your application. You will get much better performance using a stored procedure.

Comment: It is Ling to SQL. Yeah there are about 80 child categories so it makes sense that that is the problem. How would the store procedure look compared to sql statement that is being run? is there a better way to do it with a sp? thank you

Comment: After creating a single stored procedure you can drag it on to your Entity Model Diagram and it will show up in the list (not in the design view). From there you can directly call the SP and return an Entity that repersents your column output from the SP.